# A Collection that associates keys to values, and where both a key and a value can be obtained by index

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections

By *indexed* I mean keys and values can be accessed via an index representing the order in which they were inserted into the collection.

I need a collection that behaves like a `Map<K, V>`, but also a `List<K>`(Read-Only) and a `List<V>`(also Read-Only). My naive implementation is to wrap a `HashMap<K, V>` and 2 `ArrayList`, but that leads to massive data redundancy and poor perfomance. Then I thought about `LinkedHashMap<K, V>`, which would work a lot better in this case, but the `getByIndex` operations would not perform well, because that would require navigating the internal *Linked Nodes*, which for small quantities of data is perfectly acceptable, but I'm not exactly sure how will the list be used by client code.

In short, is there something that suits my requirements better than the alternative?

**EDIT:** If I had something like pointer arithmetics and low level functions like memcpy and a runtime sizeof operator resolving the sizes of K and V, then maybe I could come up with a very efficient implementation. Are there any equivalents to any of that in Java?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap

Comment: Do you need mutation, or can you settle for a structure that's built once and then stays immutable?

Comment: Why would you need *two* Lists for registering insertion order?

Comment: Android's `ArrayMap` allows access to both keys and values by index. I'm not sure at a glance whether the order is insertion order, but it's worth a look.

Comment: I contest the statement that using an additional List for maintaining insertion order would lead to "massive data redundancy". Surely you can spend one extra reference for each inserted entry.

Comment: I'd also like to learn more about a use case where *random* access to the umpteenth entry in a map is required - not to be confused with a sequential pass through the map in insertion order.

Comment: @laune I've encountered this issue before. Suppose you want to iterate over pairs of distinct keys. With an index you can do `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)`. This is completely impossible with an iterator. I concede it's not a common situation.

Comment: @PaulBoddington In that case I'd take the `new ArrayList( map.keySet() )` and proceed with the nested for statements. - If you are about to do something O(n*n) one additional O(n) isn't going to cause a ruckus.

Comment: I need mutation. A lot of it.

In my naive implementation, the assumption that I would need 2 lists for this comes from the fact that values can repeat themselves while keys can't.

People always say data redundancy is bad and should be avoided at all costs. I don't know, may I misinterpreted that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, like in a list on that aspect.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman Have a look at the source code for `ArrayMap`. I think it does what you want (but not as quickly as a `HashMap`).

Comment: If I could implement Map.Entry<K, V> it would be nice, but the compiler requires me to cast my implementation back and forth to Map.Entry<K, V> Maybe because it's parameterized?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you few indirect ways.

1. You can create `HashMap < Integer,HashMap< K,V > >`. You can insert in this map keeping order as key and then can put the Key-value pair HashMap as value.
2. You can simply have a single `ArrayList<K>` and a `HashMap<K,V>`. For each entry to the map you can insert the key in the array list.
3. You can use (as you have said in the question itself) `LinkedHashMap` and can get the `iterator` or can use `for each enhanced for loop` for iteration. This way of iterating is efficient and for each step of iteration entire list is not iterated. But you can only iterate and not get the random indexed entry.

Comment: If Java had a sizeof operator and if I could manage memory myself, then I think I would be able to do this in a very neat way, using a HashMap and some sort of Byte Buffer

Comment: @FinnTheHuman Each language has its architecture and design. Java has been designed this way. Anyways you have memory management control in other languages like C++, you can create your custom HashMap. It would be interesting to know as how would you have done in those languages. HashMap allocates the index of the element in an Array of LinekdList and the index is computed using hashCode. So these are not sequential. Now in case of two elements having same hashCode [collision case] then element is put in a new next node of the associated Linked List at that position.

Answer (score 0):

If third-party libraries are fair game, Guava's `ImmutableMap` does this nicely if you don't need mutation.  Once it's created, you can use `map.entrySet().asList()`, `map.keySet().asList()`, and `map.values().asList()` to get, in O(1), random-access lists of the entries, keys, and values that support `get(index)` in O(1).

Comment: ...which nicely hides any "massive data redundancy" - which isn't to be afraid of anyway. ;-)

Comment: Nope.  `ImmutableMap` is _still_ more memory-efficient than `HashMap` even while maintaining random access to the insertion order.

Comment: the problem is the map itself needs mutation, which must be done via the Map<K, V> interface, although the list implementation must be read-only.